# Template not found 404

Tags: templating, craft3, 404, error-templates

Having a strange issue - `devMode` is set to `false`, if I go to `/404`, I get the custom 404 page, which is great.

If I go to `/something1234567890` (which is definitely not an entry's URL) I get the following exception:

```
yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Template not found: something1234567890
```

I have tried adding debugging to my base templates but it looks like it is not getting as far as them.

Does anyone have an idea where I can start trying to debug this?

**Stack trace:**

```
2018-09-17 00:36:15 [xxx.xxx.xx.x][-][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][trace][yii\web\Application::handleRequest] Route requested: 'templates/render'
2018-09-17 00:36:15 [xxx.xxx.xx.x][-][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][trace][yii\base\Controller::runAction] Route to run: templates/render
2018-09-17 00:36:15 [xxx.xxx.xx.x][-][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][trace][yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams] Running action: craft\controllers\TemplatesController::actionRender()
2018-09-17 00:36:15 [xxx.xxx.xx.x][-][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][trace][nystudio107\seomatic\{closure}] ErrorHandler::EVENT_BEFORE_HANDLE_EXCEPTION
2018-09-17 00:36:15 [xxx.xxx.xx.x][-][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][error][yii\web\HttpException:404] yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Template not found: something1234567890 in /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php:70
2018-09-17 00:36:15 [xxx.xxx.xx.x][-][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][error][yii\web\HttpException:404] yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: Template not found: something1234567890 in /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php:70
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender('something123456...', Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#3 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(103): yii\base\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#4 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('render', Array)
#5 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(282): yii\base\Module->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#6 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('templates/rende...', Array)
#7 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(271): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#8 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#9 /home/vagrant/code/craft-site/public/index.php(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#10 {ma    in}
```

**Update 1**

The `devMode` toggling works on another Craft 3 site I have, just not this particular one. Maybe it is a database issue?

**Update 2**

I have tried this codebase with a fresh database and still getting the same error, so it must be something to do with my codebase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft will serve one of 3 types of 404 errors.

When Dev Mode is enabled, you will get something like this, which shows the full stack trace leading up to the NotFoundHttpException:

[image]

If this looks like what you’re getting, then Dev Mode is *definitely* enabled. Double-check `config/general.php` for `devMode`, or `web/index.php` for `YII_DEBUG`.

Otherwise, you will get something like this in Craft’s Control Panel (as well as the front end if you haven’t specified a 404 template yet):

[image]

If it’s a front-end request, *and* you have a 404 template, then Craft will render your 404 template. If it encounters an error when trying to do that, a plain text error will be displayed, with no styling.

Comment: `devMode` is set to `false` in `config/general.php` I swear! Is there any way to get Craft to dump what this value is before rendering the error to verify?

Comment: @MikeF Try going into your Control Panel - do you see the stripes in the top-left that indicate that Dev Mode is enabled?

Comment: Nothing there, still getting the same errors :(

Comment: OK, can you send a database backup, your `composer.json`, `composer.lock`, and config & template files over to support@craftcms.com, and tell us which URL you're getting this on? We can try reproducing it with those.

Answer (score 3):

There's a long discussion of all of this in the [Handling Errors Gracefully in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#handling-exceptions-on-the-frontend) article, if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - had a look through the article and I'm afraid the `actionRenderError()` is not being called. As you can see from my stack trace it's the `actionRender()` method I am stuck inside, and not being able to handle the `NotFoundHttpException` thrown inside there

Answer (score 3):

If you've set devMode to `false` in your local environment and you *still* can't see your 404 template, go to your own user account in the CMS and uncheck "Show full exception views when Dev Mode is disabled".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in your general.php config file and see if you're overwriting the `errorTemplatePrefix` setting. It might look something like:

`'errorTemplatePrefix' => "_errors/"`

So you might need to move the 404.html file into "/templates/_errors/" directory.

See [docs v3](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#errortemplateprefix)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - `errorTemplatePrefix` isn't being overridden in `config/general.php` though.

Comment: Also this is v3 btw

Comment: Just updated the link to v3 doc. I'd suggest making sure that Craft is definitely not running Devmode and to add the config in my answer a go and see if that makes a difference. Prefixing 404.html with a "_" or putting the 404.html in a "_errors/" directory follows best practice so the file can't be loaded when going to "exmaple.com/404.html" as this would result in returning a 200 response instead of 404.

Comment: Have tried as you have suggested and no luck unfortunately. I have updated my question to include that I've got another, smaller Craft site where I have no `errorTemplatePrefix` config and the file `templates/404.html`, and the `devMode` toggle works as expected in the docs. I am starting to think it must be something in the database which is the issue?

Comment: Okay, I haven't seen a DB issue result in this kind of thing before but you never know. Are these two Craft sites running the same version? Also If there's not too many plugins on the site you could try disabling them on by one and see if that has any effect.

Comment: Both are running 3.0.25, and I've disabled every single plugin - still getting the same as originally described :(